# Sudden increase in Ethereum's blockchain size in private network

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain-size

I am running a private Ethereum network with 100 nodes, using geth with the Proof-of-Authority consensus protocol. When measuring the blockchain size over time (using `du -cs ~/.ethereum/mychain/geth/chaindata/`), I see a steady linear increase in size (as expected since the nodes send transactions at a relatively steady rate).

However, after 437 minutes, there is a sudden increase of the size from 50 MB to 53 MB after (see plot), which is at block 932. It happens for the blockchains of all 100 nodes (i.e., it is not related to a fork).

[image: Blockchain Size]

I am wondering where this jump stems from. Is this something related to the LevelDB database workings? Can it be forecast or prevented?

More information:

`geth version`

Version: 1.10.2-stable
Git Commit: 97d11b0187b4695ccf44e3b71b54155fe405a36f
Git Commit Date: 20210408
Architecture: amd64
Go Version: go1.16.3
Operating System: linux

`geth --syncmode full`

Comment: Have you inspected block 932 and maybe surrounding blocks for clues?

Comment: so, these measurements you are makeing for the graph are for pruned chain? i.e. you stop `geth` prune, then run the `du` command? Because if not, these graph is nonsense if it is not archival node. LevelDB stores data in files, the files grow always and never get shorter. You need to compact the db to rewrite the active records and get rid of those that are marked for deletion

Comment: No, I don't prune and the measurements are taken while `geth` is running. In this application, all nodes need to run all the time; therefore, pruning is not an option and it is fine if all nodes are archive nodes. The .log file is always growing and ends up being 73 MB after 600 min (so there is no conversion from .log to .ldb). But even though it is always growing, why does it suddenly jump from 50 MB to 53 MB?

Comment: @ZiyadEdher I inspected block 932 (and surrounding blocks) but there was nothing suspicious to see: both the block size and the number of transactions in block 932 were similar to all other blocks. Therefore, I assume that is has something to do with LevelDB.

Answer (score -1):

It is likely that the sudden jump in blockchain size is caused by an increase in the number of transactions being generated, as well as the need for additional disk space to store this data. It is possible to forecast this by monitoring the trend in the number of transactions and the blockchain size over time. In order to prevent this, you could consider optimizing or reducing the number of transactions being generated or increasing the amount of disk space allocated for your chaindata.